# Is the new AlphaGo implementation using Generative Adversarial Networks?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, game-ai, generative-adversarial-networks, monte-carlo-tree-search, alphago

I read through the publication [Mastering the game of Go without Human Knowledge](https://deepmind.com/research/publications/mastering-game-go-without-human-knowledge/). It doesn't seem to use GANs, just a new form of search and reinforcement learning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, GANs are *not* used. It's reinforcement learning at what it does best. The tree search is an interesting addition and assists with navigating the sheer scale of the game.

Although the agent was playing itself to become better, there wasn't 2 separate networks (generator and discriminator). The agent learned through RL and didn't have the error calculations that generators and discriminatory have.

Comment: I found this article helpful re: what the search algorithm is: https://medium.com/@bramcohen/alphazeros-real-secret-sauce-is-mcts-b6f238d95374